# biblatex: How to ignore articles (an, the) when sorting the bibliography?

Tags: biblatex, sorting, chicago-style

I have several .bib entries whose titles start with 'An' or 'The'.  I'm using Chicago style and I have to ignore those words when sorting.  Thus "A Critical Study" should come *after* "Basic Theory," but the package places it before.  I can't find anything in the package (biblatex-chicago) documentation about this.  Is there some trick I can use, or some option I've missed in biblatex or biblatex-chicago?  (Backend is Biber, by the way).

MWE:

```
@book {book1,
author = {Tim Winton},
title = {An Open Swimmer},
}

@book {book2,
author = {Tim Winton},
title = {Breath},
}
```

When properly sorted, book1 should come *after* book2, but the package takes the word "An" into account when sorting, and it shouldn't.

Comment: Hi! Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Using the `sorttitle` field should solve the problem, i.e. add `sorttitle = {Open Swimmer, An}` or similar to `book1`.

Comment: @greyshade, thanks, that did it!  (Is there a way I can mark your comment as an answer?)

Comment: You could also use `\DeclareNosort` (can only be used with Biber):
`\DeclareNosort{\nosort{type_title}{\regexp{\AThe\s+}}\nosort{type_title}{\regexp{\A(A|An)\s+}}}` or similar (e.g `\DeclareNosort{\nosort{type_title}{\regexp{\AThe\s+}}\nosort{type_title}{\regexp{\AAn?\s+}}}`). (See p. 172 §4.5.8 *Fine Tuning Sorting* of [the `biblatex` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, try including the `sorttitle` field where necessary. Thus a complete MWE would be:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book {book1,
    author = {Tim Winton},
    title = {An Open Swimmer},
    sorttitle = {Open Swimmer, An}
}

@book {book2,
    author = {Tim Winton},
    title = {Breath},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Nothing to see here, but we refer to \textcite{book1} and \textcite{book2}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```